# Windows SDK error

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, visual-studio, registry

**Error:** Task could not find "LC.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmFFp.png) is what I have in my registry

Please help, I am stuck on this since weeks.

Comment: Did you *"make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed"*?

Comment: I need help with that as well...I moved my project from vs2010 ro vs2015

Comment: Well, do you have the Windows SDK installed?

Comment: @Lennart yes i do have it installed and need immediate help on this issue